# How to use ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular

I have a custom component `InputField` and `SignupComponent` with reactive form.

```html
<ui-input-field formControlName="email" label="email"></ui-input-field>
```

When I do like this I get `formControlName` in  `ui-input-field`, not in tag `input`. How to solve it?

I use `ControlValueAccessor` but don't understand how it work (method `writeValue()`)

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-input-field',
  template: `
  <div class="group">
    <input  required [formControlName] />
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>{{label}}</label>
</div>
    `,
  styleUrls: ['input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputFieldComponent),
      multi: true
    }]
})

export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() label: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }    

  writeValue(value) {
    if (!value || typeof value !== 'string') {
      console.log('not value');
      return;
    }
  }    

  onChange: any = () => {
  }
  onTouched: any = () => {
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched(fn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous things incorrect in your implementation:

1. The `writeValue(obj: any): void` function should be used to set the value of the input control in your component. You haven't implemented this correctly.
2. The `<input>` element within your `Component` shouldn't have the `formControlName` attribute on it.
3. `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` are supplied with a function which you should call anytime your `<input>` has changed, or was touched. You haven't implemented this.

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) should provide more than enough details on how to proceed.